# RMarkdown: how to get english error messages on a localised system

Tags: r, localization, r-markdown

I am writing a vignette in RMarkdown and I want to point out a programming mistake.

```
listofnumbers <- as.list(1:4)
listofnumbers[2] + listofnumbers[3]
```

This code snippet produces an error:

> Error in listofnumbers[2] + listofnumbers[3] :    non-numeric argument
> to binary operator

However, I am working on a system localised to German. The error message I get is in German:

> Error in listofnumbers[2] + listofnumbers[3]: nicht-numerisches Argument für binären Operator

If anyone renders the vignette themselves that may be good. But to pre-render it with the package I would need the English message.

Also, I do not want to change my system settings permanently to English.

I investigated using an [output hook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/output-hooks.html). But I do not know how to translate the German message to English.

I am working on Windows 10.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Win 10. I added it to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the environment variable `LANGUAGE` is set to `en`, error messages will be displayed in English.  This needs to be in place at the time R starts.

If you are using RStudio, then it starts a new copy of R to process vignettes when you click on `Knit`, so you can do this in the current session using

```
Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE="en")
```

That should also work if the vignette is processed when you build the package as long as you start a new session to do the build.  By default `devtools::build()` and related functions do that.

If you are running RMarkdown within the current session (e.g. by calling `rmarkdown::render()`) that won't work, because it happens too late.  In that case you can use OS features to set the environment variable, or set it in the `.Renviron` file in your home directory as

```
LANGUAGE=en
```

Since you say you are on Windows, you have to do this carefully:  Windows doesn't like filenames like `.Renviron`, and may try to change it to something else.

This method should work if you use `R CMD build` to build your packages outside of RStudio.